# Overcoming "local ambiguity: multiple parsing options:" in Rust Macros

Tags: macros, rust

I was experimenting with Rust's `macro_rules` and wanted to make a macro which could parse an HTML like syntax and simply echo the HTML as a string. The below macro gets most of the way there:

```
macro_rules! html {
    () => ("");
    ($text:tt) => {{
        format!("{}", $text)
    }};
    (<$open:ident>[$($children:tt)*]</$close:ident>$($rest:tt)*) => {{
        format!("<{}>{}</{}>{}",
            stringify!($open),
            html!($($children)*),
            stringify!($close),
            html!($($rest)*))
    }};
}
```

and then to use the macro:

```
println!("{}",
    html!(
        <html>[
            <head>[
                <title>["Some Title"]</title>
            ]</head>
            <body>[
                <h1>["This is a header!"]</h1>
            ]</body>
        ]</html>
    )
);
```

However, I would really like to remove the extraneous opening and closing square brackets. I attempt to do that as follows:

```
macro_rules! html_test {
    () => ("");
    ($text:tt) => {{
        format!("{}", $text)
    }};
    (<$open:ident>$($children:tt)*</$close:ident>$($rest:tt)*) => {{
        format!("<{}>{}</{}>{}",
            stringify!($open),
            html!($($children)*),
            stringify!($close),
            html!($($rest)*))
    }};
}
```

However, when I go to use this macro:

```
println!("{}",
    html_test!(
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>"Some Title"</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>"This is a header!"</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
);
```

I  get the `error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('children') or 1 other option.`

I know the general solution to this error is to add syntax to disambiguate the cases (such as adding the square brackets). Is there any other way around this issue for this specific example? I know using procedural macros would be an extreme solution, but I would prefer to use `macro_rules` if at all possible.

I realize using a macro to simply get a string containing HTML is overkill, but it was solely for the sake of this questions. Potentially, one could do much more interesting things with the macro such as calling functions to build up a tree representing the HTML structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want the macro to actually be usable?  Then no.  Actually, why even use a macro here at all?  No matter what you do, you're going to be fighting the Rust lexer at some point.  Just write the HTML in a string literal like:

```
r##"<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a header!</h1>
    </body>
</html>"##
```

That or accept that macro input *cannot* match actual HTML syntax, close tab, move on.

---

You're still here?  Oh, so you *don't* care about usability or performance?  You *really* want a marginal improvement in syntax, no matter the cost? **rolls up sleeves**

Be careful what you wish for.

You need to use an incremental parser, which allows you to bypass some of the ambiguous parse issues.  Rather than trying to match a non-delimited group (which you can't do), you instead recursively match unique prefixes.  Doing that leads to:

```
macro_rules! html_test {
    (@soup {$($parts:expr,)*}, [], ) => {
        concat!($($parts),*)
    };

    (@soup $parts:tt, [$head:ident $($stack:ident)*], ) => {
        compile_error!(
            concat!(
                "unexpected end of HTML; the following elements need closing: ",
                stringify!($head),
                $(",", stringify!($stack),)*
                "."
            )
        )
    };

    (@soup {$($parts:tt)*}, [$ex_close:ident $($stack:ident)*], </$got_close:ident> $($tail:tt)*) => {
        {
            macro_rules! cmp {
                ($ex_close) => {
                    html_test!(
                        @soup
                        {$($parts)* "</", stringify!($ex_close), ">",},
                        [$($stack)*], $($tail)*
                    )
                };
                ($got_close) => {
                    compile_error!(
                        concat!(
                            "closing element mismatch: expected `",
                            stringify!($ex_close),
                            "`, got `",
                            stringify!($got_close),
                            "`"
                        )
                    )
                };
            }
            cmp!($got_close)
        }
    };

    (@soup {$($parts:tt)*}, $stack:tt, <img $($tail:tt)*) => {
        html_test!(@tag {$($parts)* "<img",}, $stack, $($tail)*)
    };

    (@soup {$($parts:tt)*}, [$($stack:ident)*], <$open:ident $($tail:tt)*) => {
        html_test!(
            @tag
            {$($parts)* "<", stringify!($open),},
            [$open $($stack)*],
            $($tail)*
        )
    };

    (@soup {$($parts:tt)*}, $stack:tt, $text:tt $($tail:tt)*) => {
        html_test!(@soup {$($parts)* $text,}, $stack, $($tail)*)
    };

    (@tag {$($parts:tt)*}, $stack:tt, > $($tail:tt)*) => {
        html_test!(@soup {$($parts)* ">",}, $stack, $($tail)*)
    };

    (@tag {$($parts:tt)*}, $stack:tt, $name:ident=$value:tt $($tail:tt)*) => {
        html_test!(
            @tag
            {$($parts)* " ", stringify!($name), "=", stringify!($value),},
            $stack, $($tail)*
        )
    };

    ($($tts:tt)*) => {
        html_test! { @soup {}, [], $($tts)* }
    };
}
```

This works by crawling over the input tokens, keeping track of the string pieces that need to be output (in `$($parts)*`), and the opened tags that need closing (in `$($stack)*`).  Once it's out of input, and the stack is empty, it `concat!`s all the parts together, producing a single static string literal.

This has four problems:

1. This chews through recursion levels like crazy.  If you run out, users will need to globally up the recursion limit.
2. Macros like this are *slow*.
3. Error reporting sucks.  Although this will check the closing tags match the corresponding opening tags, problems aren't reported at any particular location in the invocation.
4. You still can't avoid needing to use string literals.  You *cannot* match an expression that is followed by `<` or another expression, so matching the strings must be the (sole) fallback rule.

So you *can* remove the delimiters, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Just quote the HTML like a sane person.

---

As an aside, here is an [alternative version of the macro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3fe3b1bc7e08b39c3f9312d64ab9031c&version=nightly) with a slightly different structure that factors out the `cmp` macro, and is easier to extend for elements without closing tags.  Note that I did not write this version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize using this macro to simply build up a string is a bit ridiculous, but that was solely for the sake of the question. I can potentially envision doing much more interesting things. I have edited my question to mention this. The biggest pain point for me is the square brackets I can look past the need to quote string literals. Do you know if rusts new `macro` system would support this? Would you recommend using a procedural macro for this?

Comment: @user7400966: Rust's new macro system doesn't exist yet, so short of time travel, I can't answer that.  As for using procedural macros, you probably could with some contortions to get around them only being supported for derives.